# Laravel controller routing with _ in the URI

Tags: php, laravel-4

I basically have to implement API commands for an external app using their URI pattern. I want to implement all the methods in a Controller so I added the following in routes.php:

> Route::controller('/ch', 'CHController');

I have to implement  GET */ch/api_function/param1/param2*. The issue is the external API's URI uses the '_' syntax for their action and laravel can't route it correctly to the right function.

The Laravel documentation for controllers here http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers suggests

> If your controller action contains multiple words, you may access the action using "dash" syntax in the URI. For example, the following controller action on our UserController would respond to the users/admin-profile URI:
>
> public function getAdminProfile() {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the routes manually in your routes file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ch'], function()
{
     Route::post('/api_function/{param1}/{param2}', ['uses' => 'CHController@function1']);
     Route::post('/another_function/{param1}', ['uses' => 'CHController@function2']);
}
```